# are these rewrite rules correct to archive following things?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, apache2

i wanted to

1. redirect all users to domain with WWW
2. im using codeigniter so wanted to remove index.php from url's
3. prevent access to index.php and redirect to domain name if someone request domain/index.php
4. wanted to 301 redirect all pages

so these are the lines i came up with .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Are these rules correct to do what i wanted to do? is there better ways to do this?

Regards

Comment: looks like half of them redundant

Comment: aren't your (2) and (3) the same?

Comment: even i remove index.php from urls like domain/index.php/controller/function, if someone request index.php it trys to show index.php thats why i try to redirect to main domain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made some changes and removed some redundant code. Here is your modified .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s(.*)/index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]
```

Also make sure your css, js, images files always use absolute path instead of relative one i.e. path to js, css, images should either start with `http://` or `/`.

Comment: After you verify it's working, pls mark it as accepted or else let me know if it is not working.